# Acquire EEG signal from GDF file and apply STFT

Tags: python, signal-processing

I am trying to process some MRCP Signals taken from [this](http://www.bbci.de/competition/iv/) (BCI Competition IV-2b,motor imagery) and I want to import the signal from GDF file **using Python** as I know it can be done easily on MATLAB. Then , I would then like to apply STFT on the signal using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459295/invertible-stft-and-istft-in-python) method based upon this description

> Short time Fourier transform (STFT) was applied on the time series for
>   each 2 s long trial. In case of 250 Hz signal, this is corresponding to
>   500 samples. STFT was performed with window size equal to 64 and time
>   lapses equal to 14.

.Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

just found out the correct solution , just load the data into Matlab/Octave and save in `.mat` format, which can be read by python easilyand you have your data in python